# GenerateWinPRTManifestV2 task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution with a windows phone 8.0 project and unit tests. I'm using VS 2013 Professional.
Suddenly when I build my solution I get the following error on the unit tests project:

> "GenerateWinPRTManifestV2" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
>      at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
>      at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.GenerateWinPRTManifestV2.CCIHarvestRegistrationInformation(ProcessWinmd processWinmd, Dictionary`2 inprocServers)
>      at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.GenerateWinPRTManifestV2.UpdateWinmdRegistration()
>      at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.GenerateWinPRTManifestV2.ExecuteImplementation()
>      at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.GenerateWinPRTManifestV2.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()

Comment: Have you looked at this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425614/error-generatewinprtmanifest

Comment: Here's another similar issue: http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2013/11/generatewinprtmanifestv2-error.html

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I was able to fix it, by removing all SQLite references which I had and add them again. Probably I mess it up when I had the references to the Unit tests project.

Answer (score 0):

I copy the zac's answer in comment because it solved my problem and maybe it might help someone else.

> I was able to fix it, by removing all SQLite references which I had and add them again. Probably I mess it up when I had the references to the Unit tests project.

What I did:

- Remove `sql-net` nuget package
- Remove `sql-net-wp8` nuget package
- Add again both packages
- Compile